# Get APEX Report column value to a page item

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

I have an APEX page with a static region and a report region (not interactive report).

Report will always display 30 questions (rows), with 10 rows per pagination.

So, Row Set "1" looks as follows.

```
Q.No__________Q.Description________Rating
01_____________AAAAAAAA________5
02_____________BBBBBBBB________3
XX ____________XXXXXXXX________N
10_____________CCCCCCC_________2
```

When next button is clicked in the report, row Set "2" looks as follows.

```
Q.No__________Q.Description________Rating
11_____________AAAAAAAA________5
12_____________BBBBBBBB________3
XX ____________XXXXXXXX________N
20_____________CCCCCCC_________2
```

And last row Set (3) looks as follows.

```
Q.No__________Q.Description________Rating
21_____________AAAAAAAA________5
22_____________BBBBBBBB________3
XX ____________XXXXXXXX________N
30_____________CCCCCCC_________2
```

My requirement is as follows.

In the static region above the report, I need to show different content based on the row set.

For first row set (questions 1 to 10), I have to show in the static region "This questions are related to AAA".

Similarly, for second row set (questions 11 to 20), I have to show in the static region "This questions are related to BBB"... and so on

For this, I was trying to get the value of the first row, first column (Q.No) of the report to a hidden page item. Based on this, I am planning to change the display text.

If it is 1, then static content will be "This questions are related to AAA"

If it is 11, then static content will be "This questions are related to BBB"

If it is 21, then static content will be "This questions are related to CCC"

I am not able to find a way to pass the value of the first row, first column of the report to a hidden page item.

Another approach would be to get the "row_set" number of the report to a hidden page item ... don't know if there is any APEX variable that gives APEX report "row_set" / "cursor" number...

Any help / suggestions / ideas please...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an easy way to do this, as far as I know.  It would be possible to write Javascript to interrogate the pagination section of the report and see what it says is being displayed.  However, given your apparently very specific 30 rows of data with associated headings, it might be easier to not use pagination at all, but instead to add your own Next and Previous buttons that set a hidden item to control pagination and then use the hidden item in the report's SQL:

```
... and question_no between :p123_que_no_hidden and :p123_que_no_hidden+9
```

Comment: Most sensible solution too I believe. You could use javascript to hook in on the after refresh event, then retrieve something, and refresh the other region. But really, what point is there in that: that only complicates it for you as a developer. Users still have to click the pagination buttons, so yes,  why not use a prev/next and control what you want to control. +1